# Mongodb find maximum scored student embeddded array

Tags: mongodb

I am new in mongodb ,Please help me out 
I have more than 500 students details like this..

```
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "name" : "Salena Olmos",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "score" : 90.37826509157176,
            "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
            "score" : 42.48780666956811,
            "type" : "quiz"
        },
        {
            "score" : 96.52986171633331,
            "type" : "homework"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "name" : "Daphne Zheng",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "score" : 22.13583712862635,
            "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
            "score" : 14.63969941335069,
            "type" : "quiz"
        },
        {
            "score" : 75.94123677556644,
            "type" : "homework"
        }
    ]
}
```

Need to find one student details who got highest marks in "type" exam
Output as follows...

```
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "name" : "Salena Olmos",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "score" : 90.37826509157176,
            "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
            "score" : 42.48780666956811,
            "type" : "quiz"
        },
        {
            "score" : 96.52986171633331,
            "type" : "homework"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need one student details from whole collection. The problem I am facing that need to search in embedded array "score" as well as "type".
Someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      scores: {
        $first: "$scores"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.scores.type": "exam"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "data.scores.score": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "$data.name",
      scores: "$scores"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

[Sample Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UqI8IBcq3xw)

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer the question, it is related. This one filters out all the subdocuments which match the conditions "greater or equal 90" and type "exam"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "scores.score": {
        $gte: 90
      },
      "scores.type": "exam"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: true,
      list: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$scores",
          as: "list",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$$list.score",
                  90
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$list.type",
                  "exam"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

which returns

```
[
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "list": [
      {
        "score": 90.37826509157176,
        "type": "exam"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Salena Olmos"
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYnVzZbuNFI

If you want the entire document, then add `doc: "$$ROOT",` to the projection.